# Extracting a substring from a string after whitespace

Tags: string, python-3.x, split

I have a string

```
S= content: form;name="Result"

content-Type: application/JSON; charset=utf-8

Context: g4g2-bg4b

{"Status":0,"result_type":"HTML:,"final_response":1}
```

I wanted to extract the substring

```
{"Status":0,"result_type":"HTML:,"final_response":1}
```

I tried using split() to split the split the string for white spaces but did not get the exact substring that I wanted.

```
s.split()
```

so, is there a way to use split() function to get the required substring after splitting it.

Comment: You can use a regular expression to extract everything between `{}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
s.split('\n')[3]
```

Usually once you split the string it becomes an array and the elements can be accessed using indices.

Answer (score 1):

What about s.split('\n')?

```
s = '''S= content: form;name="Result"
content-Type: application/JSON; charset=utf-8
Context: g4g2-bg4b
{"Status":0,"result_type":"HTML:,"final_response":1}'''

lines = s.split('\n')

print(lines[3])
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a regex for this one. Consider the following:

```
S= """content: form;name="Result"

content-Type: application/JSON; charset=utf-8

Context: g4g2-bg4b

{"Status":0,"result_type":"HTML:,"final_response":1}"""

import re
m = re.search('{[^}]*}', S)
print m.group(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use *Regular Expressions*:

```
import re
s= 'content: form;name="Result" content-Type: application/JSON; charset=utf-8 Context: g4g2-bg4b {"Status":0,"result_type":"HTML:,"final_response":1}'
s = re.sub('{.*?}', '', s)
```